# What's the name for test equipment whose accuracy can be proven from fundamental physics principles?

Tags: metrology

What's the name/phrase for a bit of equipment whose accuracy is fundamentally provable from basic physical principles?

I'm helping with calibrating some ASIs (airspeed indicators) from light aircraft. This has lead to some debate/argument with a friend about the best way to calibrate them. He favours an expensive bit of electronics with a calibration certificate (albeit slightly out-of-date), I prefer a $5 u-tube manometer with some water in it.

The manometer should be 100% accurate, so long as the height difference between the two columns is accurately measured (with just a simple ruler) and the correct maths formula is applied to relate pressure to airspeed. The expensive electronic tool merely provides convenience and ease of use, not necessarily accuracy.

So, what's the name of equipment whose accuracy can be proven from first principles?

Comment: Quality manometers have a temperature correction factor that is applied to the scale reading to compensate for the ambient temperature deviation from the calibration temperature.

Comment: Manometer's accuracy in measuring P difference is derived from accurate measurement of length and gravity. Is that really first principles? My feeling is if you want accuracy from first principles, it would apply to measurements which count things, or derive a ratiometric figure from counting things (eg ratio of two frequencies is countable).

Comment: Units are a manmade concept and so accuracy requires traceability or so NIST would have you believe... You can get great relative measurements without em though (just tells you whether A<B A>B or A~=B).  With that, you can certainly make your own units that may or may not be close to existing ones.

Comment: How do you measure the height difference in your manometer from basic physical principles? What is your local value of g?